# Implementing closure for specific method call in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I came across the following `UITableViewController` code and wanted to implement the associated `classes` and functions that go with them in order for me to learn a little bit more about Swift.

I'm not sure what the implementation of `api.getRooms()` looks like. I think it may be a closure, but I'm not entirely sure?

My question is what would `api.getRooms()` be returning considering there's `{}` usage? If anyone could explain to me what's going on that would be greatly appreciated.

```
api.getRooms(User.currentUser()!) { (roomsObj, error) in
    if let rooms = roomsObj as? Array<Room> {
        self.rooms = rooms
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        if (viaPullToRefresh) {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
}
```

**PullViewController.swift**

```
class PullViewController: UITableViewController {
    var rooms = Array<Room>()

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Custom initialization
        assert(User.currentUser())
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refreshInvoked"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        refresh()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rooms.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? UITableViewCell
        if !cell {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")
        }

        let room = rooms[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell!.textLabel.text = "\(room.name)(\(room.messageCount))"
        return cell
    }

    func refreshInvoked() {
        refresh(viaPullToRefresh: true)
    }

    func refresh(viaPullToRefresh: Bool = false) {
        let api = API()
        api.getRooms(User.currentUser()!) { (roomsObj, error) in
            if let rooms = roomsObj as? Array<Room> {
                self.rooms = rooms
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                if (viaPullToRefresh) {
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**User.swift**

```
class User {

    init() {
    }

    class func currentUser() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**Room.swift**

```
class Room {

    var name: String
    var messageCount: Int

    init() {
    }
}
```

**API.swift** *(not sure whether this is implemented correctly).*

```
class API {

    init() {
    }

    func getRooms(user: User) -> (Array<Room>, String) { // ??
        // ??
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the selector in Swift in Selector(), just provide the quoted target method name (where trailing ':' characters = parameter placeholders and no ':' = no parameters in target function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I implemented the `api.getRooms()` function:

**API.swift**

```
class API {

    func getRooms(user: User, completion: (Array<Room>, String) -> ()) {
        var room = Room(name: "Room1", messageCount: 0)

        var rooms = Array<Room>()
        rooms.append(room)

        completion(rooms, "error")
    }

}
```

**PullViewController.swift**

```
func refresh(viaPullToRefresh: Bool = false) {

    let api = API()

    if let user = User.currentUser() {
        api.getRooms(user) { (roomsObj, error) in
            self.rooms = roomsObj
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            if (viaPullToRefresh) {
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You are sending assert a void since your currentUser method doesn't return anything, so assert wouldn't know if this is good or bad. Therefore you need to make currentUser return a BOOL or something else if you want to use it like this, but it needs some sort of BOOL result to tell if it is asserting correctly or not. Hopefully that makes sense.

2)You are trying to feed your getRooms function a lambda function instead of running a function after the results.

--Update--
If you are wanting a completion lambda then you'll want to write getRooms like this:

```
func getRooms(user: User, completion: ((Array<Room>,String?) -> Void)?) -> Array<Room> {//String because I have no idea what type they want for errors
    var room = Room()

    room.messageCount = 0
    room.name = "Room1"

    var rooms = Array<Room>()
    rooms.append(room)

    completion?(rooms,nil)

    return rooms
}
```

or something along those lines

Comment: That makes perfect sense actually regarding the `assert()`. The `getRooms()` function though. I'll have to read up about lambda's in Swift and see how I could go about implementing one that works with this code.

Comment: was I right in guessing your intentions? if so you could just add an optional lambda argument to get rooms.

Comment: hopefully that example helps a bit

Comment: That helps a lot actually and makes perfect sense, however I had to add a comma before `completion:` and also there's an error that's occurring on the ?callback? `completion()` method that says: `Cannot convert the expression's type '$T3' to type '(Array<Room>, String?)?'`

Comment: Removing the `?`'s from the function then throws this error: `'(@lvalue Array<Room>, $T2) -> $Y3 'is not identical to '(Array<Room>, String)'`

Comment: Sorry about that it was late here. The code example should now be working^^; Was missing that comma and the return type of the lambda.

Comment: and parentheses around the lambda arguments

Answer (score 1):

In you room class, you did not initialize the name and message count variable, in swift only optional variable can be nil

```
class Room {

    var name: String
    var messageCount: Int

    init(name:String, messageCount:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.messageCount = messageCount
    }
}
```

also assert need to evaluate to bool so

```
assert(User.currentUser() != nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `assert()` makes sense now. Just wondering how the `api.getRooms()` function is implemented now.

Comment: you need to set name and mesageCount before init is completed, you can set in init or use optional variable var name:String?